# Difference between Lore and Story

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

One day I was having a conversation with an acquaintance about gaming and he stated that

> The game has a really good **lore**, but not much attention has been given to the **story**

So what exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particularly in role playing games or any game that takes place in a made up universe, the **lore** typically refers more to the backstory/history of either your character or the game world, while the **story** refers more to the current events of the game and the various exploits your character undergoes.

For example, in the *Halo* franchise, the different missions you go on in Halo 3 – the narrative given around them, the dialog among characters during those missions, the cutscenes that take place and such – all comprise the **story** of that game's campaign. But the broader picture of *why* you're doing that stuff, and the backstory around, for example, how it is that the Master Chief is so much taller and stronger than all the other humans, is all part of the game's **lore**. Some of that lore is explained through the narrative of the first two Halo games and opening cutscene(s) of Halo 3, and some of it comes from what you actually did as part of the campaign in those past games – which is to say that yesterday's story is part of today's lore.

This can be kind of confusing because "story" could be considered a synonym for "lore," but I suspect this is the distinction your friend was trying to draw.

So if some game has good lore but "not much attention has been given to the story," that may mean that lots of quality past updates have contributed to a rich history around the game universe, but recent updates haven't contributed to that history much (or at all). For example, in an RPG, maybe a recent slew of updates all focused on balancing, quality of life improvements, and adding new boss monsters to fight so players have fresh, challenging content, but no quests that advance existing storylines and expand on the game's backstory have been recently released.

Answer (score 2):

lore – the history of the world

story – the actual events which occur in the narrative

For more information check this , it will help

https://wikidiff.com/lore/story

https://forums.warframe.com/topic/391511-difference-between-lore-plot-and-story/

Answer (score 0):

Between quots becasuse it is not entirely true: Without the lore there is no game.

The lore makes a game more intresting and gets more people in the game than out of the game. I think that the lore covers its caracters and the time (plus / or) universe , not perse the eare or world they life/d.

The story(campaign) of a game is in the presnt.

and can be diffrent on your actions. For example: in the lore Player1 is a life and   was part of the game universe/world/game and in the story died at the begin cut cene (but a game is not a game if player1 can comeback from the death at any time of next genaration games or in the same)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).